# Instance of class's outlets are unallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, mobile

I have a subclass of `UITableCell` called `HistoriqueCell`. This class has outlets (4 labels). I have a `UIViewController` (`HistoriqueViewController` ) that has a `UITableView`. This table has a prototype cell subclassed with `HistoriqueCell`. That prototype cell's four labels are linked to the outlets of **HistoriqueCell.h**. However all my instance of those cell always have unallocated outlets. My colleague's version is working perfectly and it's the exact same code (we bypassed git and I simply loaded his copied project from his usb stick just to be 100% sure it wasn't git, even though git assured us there already was no difference).

This makes me suspect that the problem doesn't lie in the code but in a xcode config. I remember I had a similar problem way back that was due to localized *storyboard*. Simply put, the french version was loaded and had no outlets connected in it, contrary to the english version where I put the outlets. When the french *storyboard* was used the outlets were unallocated like the problem I have now, but my storyboard is not localized.

[Here's the debug showing my unallocated outlets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg4Kx.png)

[Here's the storyboard, I also have the @synthesize in the .m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78yNE.png)

[Example of cell usage :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ocXx.png)

My really really frustrated on the problem, I can't seem the find the issue. Please, if anyone have any leads I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you set "Cell" like identify ID in your code but no on your cell in Interface Builder

Comment: Man I feel dumb. It's been a while I've done this and completely forgot this part. Nice catch! I'd hug you but I hope internet points will suffice.

Comment: the important is fix the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected as nib file isn't loaded automatically.

You should either load the nib file manually by calling `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HistoriqueCell" owner:self options:nil]`.

Or preferably register the nib object with the table view as following:

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"HistoriqueCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"HistoriqueCell"];
```

And now, when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` the table view will either return a reusable cell, or create a new instance of the cell and load the nib for you. And this check won't be needed anymore:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    ...
}
```